# Catch all "subpaths" beloning to a certain controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to catch all subpaths under a controller?

Under `FooController` and `BarController` I would like to redirect all links that doesn't have a matching method in it's controller to the `Redirect` method:

```
www.domain.com/Foo/WhatEver - call Foo.Redirect()
www.domain.com/Foo/WhatEver2 - call Foo.Redirect()
www.domain.com/Bar/WhatEver - call Bar.Redirect()
www.domain.com/Bar/WhatEver2 - call Bar.Redirect()
```

I know it's possible to catch it on 404 as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420064/creating-a-catch-all-route) but I would like to catch them on a controller level.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `App_Start.RouteConfig` I added this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Foo",
                "Foo/{*arg}",
                new { controller = "Foo", action = "Redirect", arg = "" }
            );
```

That redirects all sub-paths with MP2 in it i.e.:

```
www.domain.com/Foo/
www.domain.com/Foo/SubPath/
www.domain.com/Foo/SubPath/AnotherSubPath/
```

It also includes index. If I remove the asterisk it only redirects sub-paths:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                    "Foo",
                    "Foo/{arg}",
                    new { controller = "Foo", action = "Redirect", arg = "" }
                );
```

Redirects these to the "Redirect" method under the "Foo" controller:

```
www.domain.com/Foo/SubPath/
```

It does not redirect the Index or sub-paths to the sub-path.